# How to make a table out of the value of my counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a whack a mole game and I want to make a local high-score table for it. Currently I have a counter that counts the number of successful clicks on the moles. After each session(when the window is closed/stop button is clicked) I would like the value of the counter to get saved in a high score table. It needs to be sorted by score of course. Ex:When the top score is 10 and someone gets 11 the 10 goes to number 2 and the 11 takes 1st. The table only needs to be on the local machine, input for names would be great but not needed. I need an example of this, I've tried fooling around with HTML5 databases to no avail. My counter div is

```
<div id='counter' data-counter='0'>0</div>
```

and an example of how the counter goes up one on click of a mole

```
if ($(this).data("state") == "up") {
    var counter = $("#counter");
    counter.data("counter", counter.data("counter") + 1);
    counter.text(counter.data("counter"));
}
```

I'm just starting web programming so I need it to be as noob friendly as possible. :P If you need clarification on the question, just comment.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store in the local machine, you could use cookies. You can save any string with cookies.
An easy way to use cookies with jquery is by using the jquery cookie plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

You could store a serialization of your score object, for example if you have it in an array you could do:

```
$.cookie("scores", JSON.stringify(scoresArray));
```

To retrieve it, just do:

```
scoresArray = JSON.parse($.cookie("scores"));
```

JSON functions will work in modern browsers. More information on JSON can be found on http://json.org

Hope this helps. Cheers